# NullPointerException com CDI e JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-service, cdi, injeção-de-dependência

Estou estudando `JAX-R`S e criei um simples projeto com a seguinte classe:

Código Webservice

```
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

    @Inject
    private MeuServico servico;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getText() {
        return servico.getText();
    }
}
```

Serviço

```
@Stateless
public class MeuServico {

    public String getTExtt() {
        return "Teste";
    }
}
```

Estou recebendo `NullPointerException` na linha do `return servico.getText();`
Alguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, coloque mais detalhes de sua exception e também a estrutura de seu projeto, é um .war ? um .ear ?

De qualquer forma, e muito provavelmente você deve ter esquecido de adicionar o `beans.xml` ao seu projeto, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Para projetos .war ele deve ficar sob o `WEB-INF`, para `.EAR` coloque-o na pasta `META-INF` do projeto principal (ear).

Segue um [link útil](http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/WhatIsBeansxmlAndWhyDoINeedIt) da Seam sobre o `bean.xml`(Em inglês).

Caso não seja isso por favor especifique mais.